# How can I autocomplete both HTML and Django-HTML simultaneously in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: html, django, visual-studio-code

I've installed Django support in Visual Studio Code and associated ***/templates/*.html** with **django-html** as the extension demands.

However, [it can't auto-compete **HTML Tags** as I've done so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7yYo.png).

And if I just associate HTML with itself, then [it can't intellisense **Django Template** code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhFVk.png).

How can I autocompleting **both**?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I managed to do so by:

- installing the **Django extension**
- adding the following configuration to my workspace *settings.json* file:

  ```json
      "emmet.includeLanguages": {
           "django-html": "html",
      }
  ```

Comment: What do you mean by "django support"? Can you include a link? I haven't found any extension with this name, and I already have the standard Django extensions installed.

Comment: This doesn't fix it because it's not a matter of emmet: It's a matter of a VS Code language configuration (in our case, django-html)

Comment: django support == django extension, in case you have installed, just copy this 3 lines in your workspace's settings

Comment: sorry it works for me.`django` extension aumatically adds following to your settings: 
```
"files.associations": {
        "*.txt": "plaintext",
     "**/*.html": "html",
     "**/templates/**/*.html": "django-html",
     "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
        }
```
this will associate `html` file under `templates/` directory with built-in file class `django-html`, which means it will intellisense `if else` and so on. 
My setting in the answer will associate suggestions of `django-html` with `html`. So bind `django-html` file first.

Answer (score 38):

Here is essentially the same fix, but using the VS Code UI which may make it easier for some people - especially if your new to this and your settings.json file has not been generated yet.

In VS Code go to File -> Preferences -> Settings

Once there you can switch to the 'Workspace' tab if you want this setting to only be for this project/workspace, or stick with the 'User' tab if you want this on all projects/workspaces.

Open the 'Extensions' item in the list and click on 'Emmet'.

Under 'Include Languages' click the 'Add Item' button. Fill it in with:

Item: django-html

Value: html

and click the 'OK' button.

This will add the setting for you to your settings.json file, or generate you a new settings.json file if you don't have one.
[image: Adding django-html support to VS Code]

Note: To get the autocomplete/generate to work you might need to type your tag without the brackets e.g. `li` (not `<li>`), then press enter to get `<li></li>`

Comment: Upvote for your note: "To get autocomplete/generate to work you need to type tag without brackets" !!! =)

Answer (score 8):

As [namespace_Pt said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61744003/how-to-auto-complete-both-html-and-django-html-simultaneously-in-vscode/61789506#61789506), I tried it and it works. I will list which extensions are in my Visual Studio Code installation.

1. Django 1.2.0
2. Visual Studio IntelliCode (I tried, and it works without this one)

   ```
       "emmet.includeLanguages": {
       "django-html": "html",
   }
   ```

I added it, at the end of the *settings.json* file. I find the file from the settings's search bar. Just undo what Visual Studio Code added itself and add the code above. Don't forget to add a comma.

[Where you find the .json file in settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfvMk.png)

[How it looks like after I added it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYfbZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to make it work by installing auto close tag extension and adding "django-html" language support to activationOnLanguage setting.

```
"auto-close-tag.activationOnLanguage": [
    "django-html",
    ...,
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps:

1. Install this as your extension: [Django](https://github.com/vscode-django/vscode-django)
2. Write the lines of codes in `settings.json` of your Visual Studio Code:

   ```
   "emmet.includeLanguages": {
       "django-html": "html",
   }
   ```
3. How can I get `settings.json`?

   **Answer**: The menu command *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings (*Code* → *Preferences* → *Settings* on Mac) provides entry to configure user and workspace settings. You are provided with a list of *Default Settings*. Copy any setting that you want to change to the appropriate settings. JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me (vs 1.62.3) :
in file settings.json before:

```
 "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "django-html": "html",
}
```

include:

```
{
  "files.associations": {
    "**/*.html": "html",
    "**/templates/**/*.html": "django-html",
    "**/templates/**/*": "django-txt",
    "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
},
```

Total file look like:

```
{
  "files.associations": {
    "**/*.html": "html",
    "**/templates/**/*.html": "django-html",
    "**/templates/**/*": "django-txt",
    "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
},

  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"},

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything that was listed above but nothing worked for me.
Then after much hustle I found the solution.
In your VS Code Go to..
--> File --> preferences --> settings --> workspace(if you want this setting to just be this workspace specific or "user" if you want it for all) --> extensions --> emmet--> now click on **Edit in settings.json**  --> now in that file under the curly braces that's already given, write or copy paste this ->

> "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
>
> "files.associations": {"*html":"html"},

and press **ctrl + s** to save.

It worked for me!! I hope it will work for you too.!