# What VSCode language config setting allows HTML to add extra line in a tag on enter?

Tags: html, django, visual-studio-code

What causes the extra linebreak on pressing enter between an HTML tag within VS Code (like below)?

[image]

And how can you set it up in another language without using HTML as the language's formatter (like Django-HTML for instance)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Auto-Complete both HTML and Django-HTML simultaneously in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61744003/how-to-auto-complete-both-html-and-django-html-simultaneously-in-vscode)

Comment: @Sirwill98 It does not because the given answer is incomplete and didn't solve the question author's problem and it's incomplete. That solution doesn't work anyway, that's even what the Django extension itself recommends, but not for this feature.

Comment: Also, it's not an emmet issue I don't believe. It's a language-configuration issue.

Comment: My bad i misunderstood the question, have you tried setting the setting "html.format.extraliners" to "none" in the settings.json file?

Comment: @Sirwill98 yes, but that setting only affects automatic extra lines AROUND <body> and <head> tags upon formatting, not the same functionality that works on all of them.