# how can i fix end block code in visual code?

Tags: html

I wrote some html code in visual code. They are working except the {% endblock %} ones. How can i solve this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77iik.png)

Comment: What webserver are you using for this? That `endblock` syntax looks like some sort of templating engine is running, though I don't recognize the particular one right off. So the answer is going to depend on which one.

Comment: I think this link will be helpful for you....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61744003/how-can-i-autocomplete-both-html-and-django-html-simultaneously-in-visual-studio

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
// I think it is <% EJS %> templating engine.
<% block title %> Home <% end block %>

// But I think it should be:
<%= block title %> Home <%= end block %>
```

Comment: It could also be Jinja/Flask Templating Engine, btw

Comment: Yeah. You got the point.